# Unsure about instrument abbreviations used in CD booklets

Tags: terminology, cd

I'm not a musician and my first language isn't English, so I hope I'm not asking a stupid or inaproppriate thing:

Reading a CD booklet (Verve), I see the instruments are all abbreviated, and I'm unsure about a few ones.
What I'm looking for is either some references to a list of common(?) abbreviations, or a confirmation whether my guess was right or wrong.
Here's the list:

- **vcl** *vocal*
- **t** *trumpet*
- **p** *piano*
- **g** *guitar*
- **b** *bass*
- **d** *drums*
- **tb** *trombone*
- **cl** *clarinet*
- **arr** *arranger*
- **cond** *conductor*

As "references" is considered to be a bad word when requesting answers, please ignore any references you might advise.

Comment: Can you specify the exact album you are referring to?

Comment: Is "MCN: 0731453790926" sufficient? Otherwise: "Best of Ella Fitzgerald & Louis Armstrong".